# Validate multiple selects for preference voting in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a page where users can select cast their vote for certain items in the order they choose.

There are a dynamic amount of options to choose from, e.g. there might be three options to choose from [apples, bananas, oranges], and therefore each option has a select against it, with each select then having three order of preference values [1,2,3].

The results set could be something like:

```
[apples,2],[bananas,3],[oranges,1]
```

And I'll eventually manipulate this so that I have `[oranges,apples,bananas]` in a array.

How do I validate that all options have been chosen, and that they can be seen to be in order?

Do I need to pass the data thru a loop that orders them by the chosen preference, and then counts to see if there is a missing preference?

Or am I missing a wonderful plugin that already does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the validation, and check there are votes for precisely `1, 2, 3` and no others.

```
s = [[:apples,2],[:bananas,3],[:oranges,1]]
s.map(&:last).sort == (1..3).to_a
```

To get the sorted array, use this:

```
s.sort{|a,b| a.last <=> b.last}.map(&:first)
```

EDIT (explanation): the first block works by extracting the second item of each array in the array, then checks it's equal to the range `1..3`. This validates uniqueness and presence of each item. To use this to validate in rails, you'll need a custom validator.

For the custom validator (season to taste):

```
validate :valid_votes?

def valid_votes?
  unless votes.map(&:last).sort == (1..3).to_a
    errors.add(:votes, 'are missing, duplicated or invalid')
  end
end
```

Comment: That looks pretty interesting, could you explain it a little?  And how would I validate using the code you mentioned?

Comment: Wow, thanks Peter - that's great stuff!  

I'm guessing I could pass in the length of the expected array as a parameter to the validation? The number of options is probably going to vary each time the user has a choice.

Comment: Absolutely you could pass in the parameter (anytime you see 3, replace with n).