# Validate hash of multiple select inputs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

In a similar vein to a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479219/validate-multiple-selects-for-preference-voting-in-rails)

I need to validate a group of select inputs for order of voting preference.  This time I've had to change it slightly.

The options to a user would be something like:

Choose in order of preference
1: [select with options]
2: [select with options]
3: [select with options]

The hash that this would produce could be something like:

["1" => "option-3", "2" => "option-1", "3" => "0"]

Where the 0 is a choice of no preference.

I have two questions:

1. How do I validate for the unique presence of the options selected - so there can't be multiple "option-2", but there can be multiple "0"'s (no preference)?
2. How would I validate to make sure that if someone selects 0 for the second select, they can't have an option in the third select (so with data like: ["1" => "option-3", "2" => "0", "3" => "option-1"])?

I've been trying all kinds of array manipulation but can't quite work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
valid = true
votes = (1..3).map{|x| params["select#{x}"]}
# Pass first condition
valid = false unless votes.uniq.length == votes.length
# Pass second condition
previous_is_zero = false
votes.each do |x| 
  unless x == 0 
   if previous_is_zero == true
     valid = false
     break
   else
     previous_is_zero = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that - it's looking pretty useful - but where you have params["select#{x}"] - does that mean I need to pass in the hash from the params here? Or do I need to pass in each select item?  the actual hash is params[:votes]

Comment: What i could understand is that you have 3 html selects, i considered them to be named select1,select2 and select3, you get them from params hash.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for virtual attributes and nested forms as seen in [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1).

Assuming your form is for a Ballot model that has multiple votes you should be able to do something like:

```
<%= form_for @ballot do %>
  Choose in order of preference:
  <% for votes in @ballot.votes %>
    <% fields_for "ballot[votes][]", vote do |vote_form| %>
      <%= vote_form.collection_select(:choice, vote.choices, :id %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If everything is active record you could just use that to establish uniqueness via `Ballot has_many :votes, :through => :castings, :uniq => true` or `Casting validates_uniqueness_of`. If not I would use `select` rather than `collection_select` and then you can remove duplicates by way of `#uniq` in `Ballot#votes=`.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started. The full implementation would vary depending on how normalized your data model currently is.